# GUI (Window) mono application goes into hang condition after switching GUI window tab to another window and get back to GUI window on mono

Tags: linux, mono

I am running one .NET binary using mono on my Linux platform PC and it is working fine on process startup.

But when i moved my running GUI window to another window and get back to that windows at that time , My GUI Application  goes into the hang state because i can not press any button on My GUI window.

I have also used all the optimization option step by step while running .NET binary using mono but still causes the GUI hang issue.

I have debug my .NET binary with some debugging options and found that whenever GUI window application goes into stuck condition at that GDIplus library code is running. so, it seems that there is something is going wrong into the GDIplus library.

does any one have idea what is happening here or any one have faced this issue before?

Please let me know if anyone need any more information and give valuable feedback as sson as possible.

Comment: does any one have idea about what is going on in this situation because i have tried all the way to solve above issue but could not solved that problem yet.